# About file upload in php with database

Tags: php

I am writing a code that will let me upload files. The code is to convert the file to all lowercase .Check to make sure the filename is not already inserted into the database and if the user uploads a .png or .jpg file, resize the image to a thumbnail and keep a copy of both the thumbnail and regular size image in a folder named: uploads. I am still a bit confusing cause there is something that aint right I went over and over it. I dont know if maybe I been working on it for days or what not but I can not see anything. Not only that I am still a newbie working on this.

Here is my code:

```
$aryImages=array("image/jpeg","image/png");
$aryDocs=array("application/msword","application/pdf","video/x-msvideo");
$filename=filenameSafe($_FILES['upload']['name']);
$fileType=$_FILES["upload"]["type"];
if (in_array($_FILES["upload"]["type"],$aryImages)){
    createThumb($fileType,$_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],$filename,100,100);
}
elseif (in_array($_FILES["upload"]["type"],$aryDocs)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],
"../imagefolder/".$filename);


$aryColumns=array("sessionID"=>$curSess,"fileName"=>$filename,"fileType"=>$fileType,"thumbFileName"=>$thumbFilename,"dateCreated"=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    dbInsert($filename,$aryColumns,$_FILES["upload"]["type"]);
}


    else{

    echo "File Uploaded";
  }
 }



function createThumb($type,$tmpname,$filename,$new_w,$new_h){
    $thumbFilename="tmb-".$filename;
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"jpeg"))){
        $src_img=imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);
    }
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"png"))){
        $src_img=imagecreatefrompng($tmpname);
    }
    $old_x=imageSX($src_img);
    $old_y=imageSY($src_img);
    if ($old_x > $old_y) {
        $thumb_w=$new_w;
        $thumb_h=$old_y*($new_h/$old_x);
    }
    if ($old_x < $old_y) {
        $thumb_w=$old_x*($new_w/$old_y);
        $thumb_h=$new_h;
    }
    if ($old_x == $old_y) {
        $thumb_w=$new_w;
        $thumb_h=$new_h;
    }

    $dst_img=imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_w,$thumb_h);
    imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$thumb_w,$thumb_h,$old_x,$old_y);
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"jpeg"))){
        imagejpeg($dst_img,"../upload/".$thumbFilename);
        imagejpeg($src_img,"../upload/".$filename);
    }
    if (is_numeric(strpos($type,"png"))){
        imagepng($dst_img,"../upload/".$thumbFilename);
        imagepng($src_img,"../upload/".$filename);
    }
    imagedestroy($dst_img);
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    dbInsert($filename,$thumbFilename,$type);
}


function filenameSafe($filename) {
    $temp = $filename;
    // Lower case
    $temp = strtolower($temp);
    // Replace spaces with a ’_’
    $temp = str_replace(" ", "_", $temp);
    // Loop through string
    $result = "";
    for ($i=0; $i<strlen($temp); $i++) {
        if (preg_match('([0-9]|[a-z]|_|.)', $temp[$i])) {
            $result = $result.$temp[$i];
        }
    }



    dbConnect();
    $SQL="SELECT fileID FROM upload WHERE fileName='".$result."'";
    //echo $SQL;
    $rs=mysql_query($SQL);
    echo mysql_num_rows($rs);
    if(mysql_num_rows($rs)!=0){
        $extension=strrchr($result,'.');
        $result=str_replace($extension,time(),$result);
        $result=$result.$extension;
    }
    return $result;
}




function dbInsert($filename,$thumbFilename,$type){
    dbConnect();
    $SQL="INSERT Into tblFile (fileName,thumbFileName,fileType) values('".$filename."','".$thumbFilename."','".$type."')";
    echo $query;
    exit;
    mysql_query($SQL);


}
```

I am thinking it is looping somewhere and I just cant catch it. When i click the upload button after the browse buttton the page comes up with nothing on it no picture or anything. I am not getting no error or nothing. Can someone please help me out. If i try to put some of the code out it will start giving me errors and fatal errors too. Thanks for looking.

Comment: You could make your code a bit more readable with extra spaces. Also enable `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: can you tell us what error messages you get specifically?

Comment: Well I dont have it where the codes are missing.

Comment: @mario aint the Error_reporting(E-ALL) only used if you are using the wamp or wamp server. THe programs I am using is navcat and filezila.

Comment: So, what's executing your PHP scripts then?

Comment: ok i did the database in the navicat I wrote out the scripts in textpad. I have one file name upload.php which have the php which has the script I  am showing above then I have another file name index.php which has the form information on it. They are in a folder name fileupload and in that folder is both those scripts along with a folder name upload and I already set permission with that folder. Then they all get uploaded to the filezila so they can be on the web.

Comment: I use localhost then the file on the web address bar so I can see my work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues here so I'm only going to focus on one area right now that will (hopefully) help you write better code in the future.

Your `filenameSafe()` function is terribly inefficient. Using a regex on each character of a string inside a loop is like breaking an egg with a sledgehammer with dynamite strapped to the handle. Also, if your goal is to sanitize data before saving it to the database you should be using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on the data before queries to the db.

Additionally, by simply finding the first occurrence of a period in your filename to determine where the extension starts is dubious ... what if multiple periods made it into the filename somehow? Instead, try pathinfo() to get the extension.

Finally, I assume that by appending the current timestamp you're trying to avoid filename collisions in the filesystem. This is not an adequate solution because it is very possible for two files to be saved at the same second in time. While there are whole books on subjects like hashing, for the sake of time I'll just say you'd be better served by dropping a quick [`md5()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) or [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) on the filename.

So, an example of how to better handle that particular part of the code:

```
function filenameSafe($filename)
{
    // Lower case
    $filename = strtolower($filename);
    
    // get extension
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    
    // Replace spaces with a ’_’
    $filename = str_replace(" ", "_", $filename);

    // Replace non-alphanumerics (except underscores)
    $filename = preg_replace('/\W/', '', $filename);
    
    // append the timestamp
    $filename = $filename . time();
    
    // create an md5 hash
    $result = md5($filename);
    
    // ensure the string is safe for the db query
    $result = mysql_real_escape_string($result);
    
    dbConnect();
    
    $SQL="SELECT fileID FROM upload WHERE fileName='".$result.".$ext'";
    
    $rs = mysql_query($SQL);
    if (mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0) {
        $result = str_replace(".$ext", time(), $result);
        $result = "$result.$ext";
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: I am seeing that the way i am being tought is kinda old school and it make me made. Because while I'm in school to learn and I am being tough the old way and not the new one.

Comment: well, that's the beauty of the internet -- you can teach yourself anything you want to know.

Comment: i understand how to make a simple code to do the upload but what is making me confused is adding The code is to convert the file to all lowercase .Check to make sure the filename is not already inserted into the database and if the user uploads a .png or .jpg file, resize the image to a thumbnail and keep a copy of both the thumbnail and regular size image in a folder named: uploads. I have been on this for days and everything I am reading is the same things as a simple upload file. What would be some good websites that might help explain better.

Comment: the best advice i can give is this: solve your problem in steps. isolate each part of the problem and make that one area work. for example, first figure out how to reliably format filenames how you want. then, work only on making a file upload work correctly. once you have that, format the filename of the uploaded file. finally, figure out how to perform the thumbnailing in isolation from the other functions on an image that already exists on your server. it's much easier to solve three problems separately than debugging it all together. Winning the small battles will help you win the war.